# Multiple org.eclipse.help.contexts extensions in one Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to have one Eclipse Plugin.

> Note that multiple context files from different plug-ins can be
>   associated with the context ID. This allows one plug-in to extend the
>   context help provided by another.

But this doesn't seem to work as expected. I defined them like this.

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="context_help_A.xml"
            plugin="com.a.a">
      </contexts>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="context_help_B.xml"
            plugin="com.a.b">
      </contexts>
   </extension>
```

When debugging only the com.a.a context turns up and the com.a.b context doesn't work. I don't want to deploy a plugin just to put the context file into.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this sounds lame, but did you try defining your contexts like the following?  That's how the JDT user doc plugin (org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user) does it.

```
<contexts file="..." plugin="..." />
```